# Covert wps file to PDF?

Tags: pdf, conversion, microsoft-works

I have a wps file (Microsoft Works), but no Microsoft Works, and no Microsoft Office. Ultimately, I want to get a PDF but happy to convert to an intermediate format if I can. Preferably on OS X if possible, but would use a Windows solution if there is one.

Is there a converter tool I can use for this? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/568/how-to-print-documents-to-pdf

Comment: @Sathya - or the more generic: http://superuser.com/questions/135495/how-do-i-convert-this-filetype-to-pdf

Comment: @Gnoupi ah thanks, adding that to my fav'd list so that I can point future dupes to that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/).

Comment: Excellent! Worked a treat. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure [OpenOffice](http://download.openoffice.org/) can open open `*.wps` files.
And OpenOffice have a *save as pdf option*

OpenOffice is avaliable on win and mac (among others).

Comment: right, I've tried this but it's asking me to choose a filter - I can't see a WPS filter, which one do I choose? I'm using OO 3.1.0 on  OS X.

Comment: @Steve - According to this http://superuser.com/questions/135517/what-file-types-can-openoffice-read-or-write/135520#135520 there should be something like **WPS 2000/Office 1.0 (.wps)** If you can't find that one try each in turn or go with harrymc's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's free [Word Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=3657ce88-7cfa-457a-9aec-f4f827f20cac&displaylang=en) will view, print and copy Word documents, even if you don't have Word installed.

Couple it with a virtual PDF printer, such as CutePDF, and the problem is solved.

Comment: @harrymc: nice idea, but when I open the file in the viewer it's asking me to choose the file encoding... WTF? I thought that was the computer's job?? -1 to Microsoft!  I guess it doesn't work with wps files.

Comment: @Steve Folly: Curious, the documentation does say wps files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can send the file to www.freepdfconvert.com and they will e-mail it back to you as a PDF...

Answer (score 0):

There are many free PDF printer available that would suit your needs. [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) is a good one.