# Command line Linux any document format to PDF converter?

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion, centos, command-line-tool

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert this filetype to pdf?](https://superuser.com/questions/135495/how-do-i-convert-this-filetype-to-pdf)

I am looking for tool to (similar to ooffice) convert to PDF.  I know where from .odt can be converted to PDF.  How about .doc or .docx?

```
ooffice -headless -nologo -pt cups-pdf doc.odt
```

What are the complete file formats supported? Can they all be converted to PDF?   I am looking for a solution to run on command line only tool WITHOUT a GUI.

Comment: Can someone explain what is cups-pdf here?