# doxilion document converter alternative

Tags: pdf, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting .doc files to .pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/113878/converting-doc-files-to-pdf)

Do you know of any alternative to doxilion document converter. because when I try to convert .doc files into .pdf. The images is removed and the output .pdf file will only contain text.

Please not the online converter. Because I have slow internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of free alternatives, which set themselves up as printers, rather than converters are:

- PDFCreator http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/
- PDF995 http://www.pdf995.com/

I have used both myself, and found them very good.